# jQuery animate - disable until complete

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have this bit of code that animates the background when an element with a jq class is hovered over. The code picks up current background color and animates it to a new color, then on mouse out the color is reverted back to the original. If the action is performed too quickly one after another, the code will pick up the element's background color before it is fully reverted to the original. Thus, I need to have something of the likes of jQuery animate function's complete() and if statement, but apparently it did not work for me.
How do I disable the code for the time it takes for the animation to complete?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

            var isHovered = false; 
            $(".jq").hover( 
             
                 if(!isHovered) {            
                    isHovered = true;
                    function(){ 
                        var bgcol = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
                        $(this).animate({     
                            backgroundColor: "#DDD",
                            color:"#111"
                        }, trans).data('hoverbackground', bgcol);
                    },
                    function() {      
                        $(this).animate({
                            backgroundColor: $(this).data('hoverbackground'),
                            //backgroundColor: "#EFEFEF",
                            color:"#888"
                         }, trans, complete: function() {
                         isHovered = false;}).removeData('hoverbackground');
                    }
                  });                         
                });
```

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sorted it out, partially solving the problem. The behaviour is removed until the animation is finished, but by referring to any jq classed element in the function makes one's element isHovered affecting any other element that is hovered immediately after. In other words, the function does not distinguish which element the animation is finished on.

```
 $(".jq").hover( 


                function(){ 

                    if(!isHovered) { 
                     isHovered = true;
                        var bgcol = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
                        $(this).animate({     
                            backgroundColor: "#DDD",
                            color:"#111"
                        }, trans).data('hoverbackground', bgcol);
                }},
                function() {   

                    $(this).animate({
                        backgroundColor: $(this).data('hoverbackground'),
                        //backgroundColor: "#EFEFEF",
                        color:"#888"
                    }, trans, function() {
                    isHovered = false;}).removeData('hoverbackground');

               });   

    });
```